# Blend + VS 2012 Ultimate Form Missing in VS

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, blend

I created a WPF form in Blend and now I want to bring this form into VS2012 so I can start putting code to the buttons, etc. I cannot open projects from VS2012 directly into blend the shortcut to do this isn't there, but I can edit my Blend project in VS2012. When I do this and run the project in VS2012 I see the form as expected which I've created in blend. The problem is in VS I cannot find the actual form anywhere to work with, I can only edit the files themselves. Not sure if I'm doing something silly, but I'm trying to click into buttons to create events like I would normally. Any ideas what I'm missing?

When I open other WPF projects that I started in VS2012 (not blend) the form comes right up for me to interact with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VS open the xaml for the form.  If you can't see the designer, look at the bottom of the xaml window, there should be some tabs there: XAML, Design and Document Outline.  Selected Design will switch your view from the Xaml to the 'Form view' (the designer).  If you look on the right there are some buttons for changing the view to a split view, either vertically or horizontally that allow you to see both the Xaml and the design at the same time.  You can end up in the state where you don't see the form if you expanded the xaml view to fill the pane.

[image]

The horizontal view will look like this:
[image]